# Routing Individual Post with Pagination - Flask

Tags: python, pagination, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Goal: Route to an individual article/blog post and include pagination (using SQL-Alchemy) so that the user can easily navigate to the prior and future post.

Currently, I have the following:

```
@app.route('/articles/ind/<int:id>', endpoint='article')
def indarticle(id = 1):
    posts= Post.query.paginate(id, 1, False)
    return render_template('article.html',
        title = "Article",
        posts = posts)
```

As can be seen, I am displaying one article per page, so assuming the articles start from ID = 1, the ID and page number match up. However, if they don't match (or an article is deleted from the database), the routes and rendered pages don't match up. I could easily loop through the rows of the table to find which page number corresponds to the correct article ID; however, that doesn't seem very efficient or practical.

What is the best way to get around this?

Update: 
Iterating on the answer from below, I have created the following:

models.py

```
class Post(db.Model):
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
title = db.Column(db.String(100))
body = db.Column(db.Text)
timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime)
user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))

def get_count(self):
    return db.session.query(Post).count()

def prev_post(self):
    count = self.get_count()
    pid = self.id
    while (count > 0):
        prev_post = None
        pid = pid - 1
        if db.session.query(Post).get(pid) is not None:
            prev_post = db.session.query(Post).get(pid)
            break
        else:
            count = count - 1

    return prev_post

def next_post(self):
    count = self.get_count()
    pid = self.id
    while (count > 0):
        next_post = None
        pid = pid + 1
        if db.session.query(Post).get(pid) is not None:
            next_post = db.session.query(Post).get(pid)
            break
        else:
            count = count - 1

    return next_post

def has_prev(self):
    return True if self.prev_post() is not None else False

def has_next(self):
    return True if self.next_post() is not None else False
```

This way, I can get the next post, previous post, as well as easily check if they exist, much like how flask-sqlalchemy handles pagination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make sure we are talking about the same thing, there are two types of pagination....

First, the kind that Flask supports.... Call all articles and display X posts per page...

Second, you are in a post and want to go forwards and backwards.

Sounds like you are looking to do the second kind.

What I did is write two staticmethods in my POST model that figure out the previous and next post...  I then pass the value to the template via my view function.

**POST Model staticmethods**

**MODEL**

```
@staticmethod
def prev_post(pid):
    count = Post.get_count()
    while (count > 0):
        prev_post = None
        pid = pid - 1
        if db.session.query(Post).get(pid) is not None:
            prev_post = db.session.query(Post).get(pid)
            break
        else:
            count = count - 1
    return prev_post

@staticmethod
def next_post(pid):
    count = Post.get_count()
    while (count > 0):
        next_post = None
        pid = pid + 1
        if db.session.query(Post).get(pid) is not None:
            next_post = db.session.query(Post).get(pid)
            break
        else:
            count = count - 1
    return next_post
```

How the prev_post function works.

1. use the post count to set the range of my while loop.
2. in the case of prev_post, assign a None value so the template logic works if nothing previous is found. Also, if None is not assigned and you try to pass in your view you get an error.
3. in the case of prev_post, on each loop pass subtract 1 from the pid and check to see if an entry exists in the db.
4. iterate through the loop, subtracting 1 each time.
5. the first time you find a match, break the loop and replace the prev_post none value with the post.id.

Of course, the next function is exactly the same except you +1 the pid instead of -1.

This solves your problem of deleting posts and showing the wrong number.  Also, notice I don't have to return all the posts and loop through them.  I simply get a count and and check if the pid exists one at a time.  I rarely have to go through more than 2 or 3 loops before I get a hit because the loop always starts relative to the current post. In short, a relatively small amount of memory is used for this process.

Now I can call these functions in my view...

**view**

```
@app.route('/<path:url>', methods=['GET', 'POST']) def
display_post(url):
    post = Post.get_post(url)
    next_post = Post.next_post(post.id)
    prev_post = Post.prev_post(post.id)
    return render_template('post.html',
                           next=next_post, prev=prev_post, post=post)
```

Here is the template.

**template**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}{{ post.title }}{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<H2>{{ post.title }}</H2>
<b>Posted {{ post.pub_date|dts }} in <a href="{{ url_for('display_topic', url=post.topic.url) }}">{{post.topic}}</a></b>
{{post.body|markdown}}
{% if prev.url is defined %}
<a href="{{ url_for('display_post', url=prev.url) }}"><<< {{prev.title}}</a>
{% endif %}
{% if prev.url is not defined and next.url is not defined %}{% else %} | {% endif %}
{% if next.url is defined %}
<a href="{{ url_for('display_post', url=next.url) }}">{{next.title}} >>></a>
{% endif %}
{% if current_user.is_authenticated() %}
<p><a href="{{ url_for('edit_post', url=post.url) }}">edit</a></p>
<p><a href="{{ url_for('delete_post', url=post.url) }}">delete</a></p>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

The template only display the link if a next or prev post exists.

Comment: I love the strategy; however I am making a few changes/upgrades to it to make it a little bit more like the pagination function in flask-sqlalchemy! Will be posted soon!

Comment: Cool. Please take a look at the **if db.session.query(Post).get(pid) is not None: ** lines. They could probably be improved upon. In the meantime, please close the question if you feel it's been appropriate answered. You can update your response later.